# How can I make Grouped Bar Plots in R?

Tags: r, bar-chart, data-visualization

[image]

```
     City
             2018-2019
                      2019-2020
                                2020-Present
1   Amritsar    0.0365  0.0205  0.0284
2   Jalandhar   0.0034  0.0031  0.0020
3   Ludhiana    0.0238  0.0235  0.0151
4   Moga        0.0105  0.0038  0.0202
5   Pathankot   0.0157  0.0013  0.0070
6   Phagwara    0.0100  0.0100  0.0114
```

I need to code a grouped bar graph such that the City names are on the horizontal axis and for each city, I can see three bars corresponding to the rejection rates for each of the three years.

It would be super helpful for me to be walked through how to code this in R.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This looks like a duplicate question, so take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591363/two-bars-next-to-each-other-using-geom-bar/48591449#48591449) and see if that works for ya

Comment: It is almost definitely a duplicate, searching SO for [`[r] grouped bar plot`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+grouped+bar+plot) has many examples. Ananya, it can be difficult to search for relevant questions, but it can save a lot of time to do that before asking a question. Adding the `[r]` literal (brackets around `r`) helps on SO because it forces the R programming language tag, which narrows down the search significantly.

Comment: I think the hardest time you're going to have is that column names shouldn't start with a number in R, so you're going to have to fix the automatic changes that occur when you try to import the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stacked bars within grouped bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486501/stacked-bars-within-grouped-bar-chart)

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be pretty easy if you're importing from Excel (which is what that screenshot looks like?). Just use the `readxl` package and it names the columns appropriately.

```
library(readxl)
data <- readxl::read_xlsx("data.xlsx")
data
## A tibble: 6 x 4
#  City      `2018-2019` `2019-2020` `2020-Present`
#  <chr>           <dbl>       <dbl>          <dbl>
#1 Amritsar       0.0365      0.0205         0.0284
#2 Jalandhar      0.0034      0.0031         0.002 
#3 Ludhiana       0.0238      0.0235         0.0151
#4 Moga           0.0105      0.0038         0.0202
#5 Pathankot      0.0157      0.0013         0.007 
#6 Phagwara       0.01        0.01           0.0114
```

Now we need to make the data longer so it can be plotted by `ggplot`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-City, names_to = "Period", values_to = "Value")
## A tibble: 18 x 3
#   City      Period        Value
#   <chr>     <chr>         <dbl>
# 1 Amritsar  2018-2019    0.0365
# 2 Amritsar  2019-2020    0.0205
# 3 Amritsar  2020-Present 0.0284
#...
#16 Phagwara  2018-2019    0.01  
#17 Phagwara  2019-2020    0.01  
#18 Phagwara  2020-Present 0.0114
```

Then we can use `ggplot`. The `aes` function tells `ggplot` what to use for what property of the graph. We can tell it to put `City` on the `x` axis, `Value` on the `y` axis, and change the bar `fill` based on the `Period`. `geom_bar` tells `ggplot` we want a bar plot. `position = "dodge"` means we want grouped bars. `stat = "identity"` means we don't want any transformations of the data. These arguments are things you'll just have to look up until you're more experienced.

```
library(ggplot2)
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-City, names_to = "Period", values_to = "Value") #%>%
ggplot(aes(x = City, y = Value, fill = Period)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  labs(y = "Rejection Rate")
```

[image]